# how to use AppDelegate Function in ViewController in macos application

Tags: ios, swift, macos, cocoa

I am a rookie ios developper . I am confused about how to use a function that I have defined in Application. here my Code

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
 
 
 func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {

 }

 // I try to use this function in my View's Button
 func test()  {
     print("test")
 }
}
```

I also have use this code in my View

```
let appDelegate = NSApp.delegate as! AppDelegate

appDelegate.test()
```

but I have error say

```
could not cast value of type 'SwiftUI.AppDelegate' (0x7fff8a2c6110) to 'learnSwift.AppDelegate'
```

thanks all you answer my question

Comment: SwiftUI is only mentioned in the error, but this information is crucial. You have to implement `@NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor` in the `App` scene.

Comment: thank you fro answer my question, i do the thing that you tell , i write the code in App scene and in the view , now it can call the methods, but i have init the wsTask in AppDelegate, and i want to call the methods to send the message in view , but it says the wsTask is nil , according to the server's log, it had init successfully. so i am so confused about this situation

Comment: Avoid AppDelegate if possible. AppDelegate is only useful if the application delegate methods (or other NSObject related delegate methods) must be used. initialize custom classes in a view model (a class conforming to `ObservableObject).`